# My Database Design skills stink. Where to seek remedy?

Tags: performance, database-design, database-performance

I have a web site that's been progressivelly expanding in both traffic and complexity of database design. I've always worked as a developer first & foremost, and never really been much of a DB administrator beyond what I need to do to get my code running. This needs to change - I need to improve efficiency on the database side of things.

To give a vague example, I'm looking for how to go about learning:

- Optimising complex tables/relationships for performance/scaling
- How to index efficiently. (At the moment I throw indexes on foreign keys, and that's about it)
- General design principles for complex databases

Most of the resources I've found are either directed more towards the basics of SQL ("this is a SELECT query, a JOIN, etc") or focus primarily on performance issues outside the DB.

So, I know this is a little vague - but where should I look to ensure my database is designed in the most most efficient & integral manner possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Learn about data modeling. Choosing the right data structure is always a crucial first step, for programming in general and databases in particular. Performance cannot be "bolted" on top of a bad data structure! The [**ERwin Methods Guide**](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20ERwin%20Data%20Modeler%20r8-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/PDF/ERwin_Methods.pdf) is probably not a bad way to start learning about data modeling.
2. Learn how DBMSes organize data at the physical level. This will help you immensely in understanding how to "shape" your data for performance and how to effectively leverage many of the performance mechanisms modern DBMSes put at your disposal. [**Use The Index, Luke!**](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) is an excellent tutorial on the topic.
3. Learn how to efficiently *access* the database and make sure you really understand the client API that will be called from your code. Different APIs have their own idiosyncrasies, but they all share some common themes, such as parameter binding, query preparation and fetching. Even if you are "shielded" by an ORM from ever having to, say, bind parameters manually, this is still taking place "under the covers" and understanding it raises your ability to write performant code.
4. Measure, measure, measure. Modern information systems are immensely complex and even experts find themselves making incorrect assumptions, so don't rely on assumptions!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest some reading in performance tuning. It is very specialized depending on the database backend you use. BUt here are some books to consider:

SQl Server
[http://www.amazon.com/Server-Query-Performance-Tuning-Distilled/dp/1590594215/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334154710&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594215)

[http://www.amazon.com/Performance-Tuning-Server-Dynamic-Management/dp/1906434476/ref=sr_1_12?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334154710&sr=1-12](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1906434476)

MySQL 
[http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-ebook/dp/B0028N4W7Y/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1334154504&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0028N4W7Y)

Oracle
[http://www.amazon.com/Oracle-Database-Release-Performance-Techniques/dp/0071780262/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334154909&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071780262)

General performance Tuning
[http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Performance-Tuning-Peter-Gulutzan/dp/0201791692/ref=sr_1_18?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334154964&sr=1-18](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201791692)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, I'd recommend learning how to use EXPLAIN and what its output means. Run it on your most common queries and study the output. Are the queries using sensible indexes? Are they using indexes at all? Queries that look very simple at a glance might end up being quite costly.

Next, I'd suggest finding your slowest queries. Postgres (for example) has a feature that allows you to log the SQL source for all queries that take longer than N seconds to run. Are they slow because they're unindexed, very complex, or operating on a huge amount of data?

Third, I'd look at the number of times a particular query is run. Are you using the database to store static data, and hitting a table over and over again to grab a record that never changes? You could probably cache the result somewhere.